# stop autorun of networking services at startup Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

i am trying to disable the networking services from starting up automatically;
i am thinking avahi-daemon, network-manager, and networking from the /etc/init.d/ folder;
what do i do to keep them from running automatically?
move them from /init.d/ ?
then to where?
and are there other networking services that i should be aware of?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the startup symlinks of these files using `update-rc.d`:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d -f NetworkManager remove
$ sudo update-rc.d -f networking remove
$ sudo update-rc.d -f avahi-daemon remove
```

this will stop these applications from running automatically on startup.

To re-add them later on, simply run:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d NetworkManager defaults
$ sudo update-rc.d networking defaults
$ sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon detaults
```

Comment: thanks; tried to 'vote up' but apparently dont have the rep; need to read on the way this site works;

Comment: @bboy if this solution worked for you, you can simply check the answer as 'accepted' :)